# How to filter an array of objects based on multiple properties in JavaScript/Typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter, filtering

What is the best way to filter an array of objects based on multiple property conditions and preserve the original order.
So what has to happen is to filter the array based on these two conditions:

- Most recent version
- Valid ones { invalid: false }

In other words leave only the valid ones and ones with highest version number(version number could be any).

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'John',   invalid: false, version: 1 },
  { name: 'John',   invalid: false, version: 2 },
  { name: 'John',   invalid: true,  version: 1 },
  { name: 'John',   invalid: true,  version: 5 },
  { name: 'John',   invalid: true,  version: 2 },
  { name: 'Samuel', invalid: false, version: 1 },
  { name: 'Samuel', invalid: false, version: 2 },
  { name: 'Samuel', invalid: true,  version: 1 },
];
```

to...

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'John',   invalid: false, version: 2 },
  { name: 'Samuel', invalid: false, version: 2 }
];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That sounds less like a `filter`; the result requires a pass through all the data (unless it's ordered) in order to determine the "most recent version".

Comment: Please [edit] your code to make it a [mre] with no typos or undeclared values.  Commas and `valid`-vs-`invalid` immediately jump out as issues that you're not asking about.  You should check it in an IDE to make sure it actually demonstrates your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a lookup table, this is in O(n) runtime.

Basically iterate once through the array, remember for each valid name the highest version you saw, and then use that table as a filter for the original array.

```
const lookup = {} as Record<string, {name: string, version: number, invalid: boolean}>;
arr.forEach((it) => {
  const stored = lookup[it.name];
  if (stored) {
    if (!it.invalid && it.version > stored.version) {
      lookup[it.name] = it;
    }
  } else {
    lookup[it.name] = it;
  }
})

const filtered = arr.filter((it) => {
  const stored = lookup[it.name];
  const result = !it.invalid && it.version === stored.version;
  if (result) {  //if no duplicates wanted
    delete lookup[it.name];
  }
  return result;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, good solution and also preserves the order.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Update the object corresponding to a particular `name` only if:

- it's valid
- it's new
- it has a higher version that the currently stored object

```js
const data = [
  { name: "John", invalid: false, version: 1 },
  { name: "John", invalid: false, version: 2 },
  { name: "John", invalid: true, version: 1 },
  { name: "John", invalid: true, version: 5 },
  { name: "John", invalid: true, version: 2 },
  { name: "Samuel", invalid: false, version: 1 },
  { name: "Samuel", invalid: false, version: 2 },
  { name: "Samuel", invalid: true, version: 1 },
];

const result = Object.values(
  data.reduce((acc, d) => {
    if (d.invalid) return acc;
    if (!acc[d.name] || d.version > acc[d.name].version) {
      acc[d.name] = d;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

In TS, you can create separate types for valid and invalid data using the union type.

```
type ValidData = { name: string; invalid: false; version: number };
type InvalidData = { name: string; invalid: true; version: number };

const data: (ValidData | InvalidData)[] = [
  { name: "John", invalid: false, version: 1 },
  { name: "John", invalid: false, version: 2 },
  { name: "John", invalid: true, version: 1 },
  { name: "John", invalid: true, version: 5 },
  { name: "John", invalid: true, version: 2 },
  { name: "Samuel", invalid: false, version: 1 },
  { name: "Samuel", invalid: false, version: 2 },
  { name: "Samuel", invalid: true, version: 1 },
];

const result = Object.values(
  data.reduce((acc: { [name: string]: ValidData }, d) => {
    if (d.invalid) return acc;
    if (!acc[d.name] || d.version > acc[d.name].version) {
      acc[d.name] = d;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks looks like a good solution.
Also fixed one typo in my example as there was one object in the array that had "valid" instead of "invalid" prop.

Comment: How is this the accepted solution? It does not preserve order. Javascript does have a pattern to object property order, but it is NOT insertion order (related to it, though)

Comment: @VoidedName, yes you're right, I just noticed that.

Comment: @VoidedName The original question did not specify the order needed to be preserved.

Comment: @DaveNewton, that's also true. I've added that later in the question, which is my fault, but yes order preserve is required.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing this in several stages. Assuming that the order of the array isn't important, you can `.sort` it so the most recent version is first, and keep track of which you have added, and also filter out invalid ones. Something like this:

```js
function filterThing(thing) {
  const added = new Set();
  return thing.sort((a, b) => b.version - a.version).filter((item) => {
    if (thing.invalid || added.has(thing.name)) {
      return false;
    }
    added.add(thing.name);
    return true;
  }
}
```

If you need to have the items in another order, you could sort after that. If you need to preserve the original order of the items, that's a more complicated algorithm.

Comment: Yes, array order should preserve the original order.